# Macro that resolves to a 'where' condition in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, macros

In the `psql` shell, I'm always writing queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE date >= '11-01-2016' AND date < '12-01-2016'
```

It would be nicer to be able to write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE IN_MONTH(11)
```

and have `IN_MONTH` resolve to the appropriate condition. Does the Postgres concept of 'user-defined functions' apply in this case? Wording in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/xfunc.html)

> SQL functions execute an arbitrary list of SQL statements, returning the result of the last query in the list.

makes me think they do not, and I need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create SQL functions, which are sometimes inlineable if not marked `STRICT`. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION in_month(date, integer)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
SELECT extract('month' FROM $1) = $2
$$;
```

This is not generally indexable though, unless you have a expression index on `extract('month' from columnname)`. If you're only interested in a month in one particular, not any date within that month in any year, it's more efficient to pass a date instead of an integer month number and use `between`, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION in_month(date, date)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
SELECT $1 
  BETWEEN date_trunc('month', $2) 
  AND (date_trunc('month', $2) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
$$;
```

since that allows use of a b-tree index on the date column to scan for a range. It's *simpler* to write `date_trunc('month', mycol) = date_trunc('month', 'thedate')`, but it won't be able to use an index on `mycol`, it needs a separate index on `date_trunc('month', mycol)`. Since extra indexes cost performance, don't add them if you can rephrase the query instead.

Postgres will frequently "inline" such functions - effectively macro-expanding them. You can tell if they've been inlined by looking at `explain` output.

Comment: Thank you -- I didn't even know Postgres functions could return the whole universe of data types (e.g. a boolean). Looks like `extract('month' FROM date) = 9` is actually all I need.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* write:

```
where date_trunc('month', date) = date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

However, Postgres would not use an index for resolving the query (if an appropriate index were available).